# Creating a Java class on the fly from a CSV structure

Tags: java, class, csv

I have a CSV file that I extract. 
Here is an example of extracted data:

```
name;town;zipcode
foo;bar;55555
test;there;6666
```

What I want, is to create the correspondent class on the fly that will match the CSV structure (which is the first line as it contains the fields).

Is it possible with Java to create that class (on the fly) at runtime  (ex: Person) and use it then as a "normal" class (`Person person = new Person()`) ?

Regards.

Comment: Yes I'm assuming you could use reflection, but why would you want to do such a thing? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: the CSV fields can Vary ... and I want to explore this kind of programming skills.

Comment: There is little reason for this in the first place: what good is having a compile-time "defined" class for data that may vary at runtime? The correct way to handle a case like this is through an hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this ... but I don't think it would be a good idea.

Basically, you would need to:

- Read the first line of the CSV file an use it to figure out the names of the fields; e.g. "name", "town", "zipcode".
- Read the second line of the file and try to intuit sensible types for the fields; e.g. string, string, integer.
- Generate source code for the class with declarations for the fields, a constructor and/or getters and setters for each of the fields.  The class could also include code for parsing the CSV file.  (I'd use some Java-based templating engine such as Velocity or FreeMarker to generate the code, but you could do it by string bashing.)
- Call the Java compiler to compiler the source code.
- Use dynamic class loading to load the compiled class.
- Use reflection to create instances of the class and/or call methods on them.

So why do I think it is a bad idea?  A couple of reasons ...

- The step of "intuiting" the types of the fields is heuristic, and could be unreliable.  For instance, though we intuited that the `"55555"` was a number, in fact it is a symbol and would (arguably) be better represented as a string.  (For instance, suppose that the 3rd line of the file had a British postcode `"CB2 1QG"` instead of an American zipcode.)
- The generated class pretty much *has* to be used reflectively.  Java is a statically typed programming language, and you can't write statically typed code to use a class whose API is not known at compile time.  This means ... for example ... that the sample code in your question

  ```
     Person person = new Person();
  ```

  could not be compiled until *after* you'd generated and compiled the class from the CSV file.  (It would even be tricky to use a generated class using reflection, except to do totally generic things.)

---

The bottom line is that you are probably best off either writing the class for the CSV file by hand, based on your understanding of what the fields actually mean.  If you do generate the class, then it is probably to do this as a development time activity so that you can write (or generate) code that can be statically compiled against the class.

Comment: +1 for the explanation that the class would have to be used reflectively.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a complete list of fields, in which case you can build a Person class with all the fields, and determine from the CSV which fields can be filled...

If you want it more dynamic, either use a hashtable or go through the hassle described by Stephen C...

But beyond the method what are you trying to do ?